# What does "shape information" mean in terms of GAN(generative adversarial networks)?

Tags: terminology, generative-adversarial-networks

A paper [says](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31696163)

> However, annotations used as inputs to C-GAN are typically based only on **shape information**, which can result in undesirable intensity distributions in the resulting artificially-created images.

What does "shape information" mean here?

I am aware of basic concept of GAN([generative adversarial networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network)), though I don't understand what "shape information" refers to.

[image]

I am aware the image above is an illustration of Image Segmentation. Would I think of the any one of the segmented area (red, green, blue) as a shape for a GAN?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this paper if you can access through paywall: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0923596500000205